# How do you select a specific child div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you select a div which is a child of the current $(this)?

I have many divs with the class row, in each of which I have a hidden div called form_explanation. I want to show() the div form_explanation when the row is onClick-ed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.row').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).children('div.form_explanation').show();
});
```

If you want to hide all other divs:

```
$('.row').bind('click', function () {
    $('div.form_explanation:visible').hide();

    $(this).children('div.form_explanation').show();
});
```

Comment: This only works if the div has a class="form_explaination", which should be the case. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: If you have several rows, you probably want to use '.live' in place of '.bind'. It is significantly more efficient in older browsers.

Comment: @Walker: What do you mean? `onClick` is not a jQuery method. Do you mean `click`? or the DOM elements `onClick` method?

Comment: by onclick I mean $(object).click(function() {

Comment: @Walker: `$().click()` is just a shortcut for `$().bind('click', ..')`. Both will work. With the jQuery additions of `live()` and `delegate()` in the latest version releases, I just think it's more meaningful to use `bind()` than `click()` directly.

Comment: @Matt: Sure, I'll definitely start doing that.  Is there a way to select the div form_explanation from div on the same level?

By that I mean that inside of <div class="row"> there is <input class="has_explanation"> and <div class="form_explanation">.  Could I place a .bind('click' on the <input> and have it select the form_explanation div?

Comment: I'm currently   using$(this).parent().children('div.form_explanation').show();  but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way.

Comment: @Walker: Check out the `siblings` method: http://api.jquery.com/siblings. Your code will be `$(this).siblings('div.form_explanation').show();`

Comment: @Matt: Thanks!  You've been a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children("div.form_explanation")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out for your specific problem

```
$('.row').click(function() {
    $('div#form_explanation').show('fast'); //or div.form_explanation you didn't specify
});
```

with regards to the first part of your question, you could do something like this in general:

```
$(this).children('div');
```

or something like if you don't have the `$(this)`

```
$('parent > child');
```